# why shifting array with a push copies last value to second last element?

Tags: javascript

I was working on a code in which I needed to convert strings to numbers in an array. I tried this-

```
 for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
   arr.push(parseInt(arr[i]));
   arr.shift();
}
```

What turned out to be weird for me is that the values returned were correct but at the end of array, the values of last and second last element always turned out to be same(i.e. the expected value of the last element),whereas this worked perfectly fine-

```
l= arr.length;  
for(var i=0;i<l;i++){
arr.push(parseInt(arr[i]));
}
var temp=begin.splice(0,l);
```

I am curious that why the first method didn't work because according to me it should. Any kind of help would be great.

Comment: What does the array look like?

Comment: Also trying to convert Array of Number Strings to Numbers, try `arr.map(Number)`

Comment: something like this- ["2016","09","01"] @abhisekp

Comment: @abhisekp i know there are alternatives but i want to know why this one didn't work?

Comment: On each iteration you add an element to the end, remove an element from the start, and then still increment your loop counter `i`, so you're skipping over some of the original elements and you're reprocessing some of the new ones. If you did `arr.push(parseInt(arr[0]));` and didn't change anything else it would work, but it's a really weird way to do it.

Comment: Just use `arr.map(Number)`.

Comment: To figure out what your code is doing and why it is not working, open your debugger, and step through it line by line. Or emulate your logic on a piece of paper, writing out the value of `arr` and `i` at each step.

Comment: @nnnnnn yes and thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You changed both the *input* array and the index (`i`) which you used to read from the *input*.

Assuming you have the `["2016","09","12"]`  then on the first iteration `i` is `0` and you do your `arr.push(parseInt(arr[i])); arr.shift()` then the result is:

`["09","12", 2016]` and `i` is incremented to `1` so at the next step you read `"12"` instead of `"09"`

Comment: okay,i got that! This was making me crazy, silly still worth noting mistake. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @srishtisharma you should always use the debugger for such question and step through your code. That would have have saved you much time.

Comment: okay,actually i was solving the question online. Thanks for the suggestion. :)

Comment: @srishtisharma The debugger is also available there.

Answer (score 1):

Let the array `arr = ["2016","09","01"]`

Now lets move the loop step by step (which you can easily do using chrome debuggger tool)

```js
var arr = ["2016","09","01"]
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr.push(parseInt(arr[i]))
  arr.shift()
}

console.log(arr)
```

**Iteration 1**

1. `i = 0`
2. `arr.length = 3`
3. *take `index 0` element, shift out 1st, push to the last*
4. `arr = ["09", "01", 2016]`

**Iteration 2**

1. `i = 1`
2. `arr.length = 3`
3. *take `index 1` element, shift out 1st, push to the last*
4. `arr = ["01", 2016, 1]`

**Iteration 3**

1. `i = 2`
2. `arr.length = 3`
3. *take `index 2` element, shift out 1st, push to the last*
4. `arr = [2016, 1, 1]`

And boom, your result is on the table.

Hence, the 1st algo is a very very bad one.

Comment: You should use the `radix` when using `parseInt` because older browser might treat  a string starting with `0` as octal, so using `parseInt(a)` with `"09"` could result into `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Your first function is reading and deleting array elements at the same time in 1 iteration . Refer fail fast array.

Dry run:

'1','2' is initial array .

After 1st iteration it will be '2',1

Now 2nd iteration has i=1

But ar[1]=1 , so it will again push 1 and final array is 1,1 .

Hope you got the point.

**Better solution**:
Use JavaScript map.

`var newAr=ar.map(function(a){
 return parseInt(a);
});`

Comment: You should use the `radix` when using `parseInt` because older browser might treat  a string starting with `0` as octal, so using `parseInt(a)` with `"09"` could result into `0`.